# is there a function in win32 API to detect the "refresh" action and create a notification when the user refresh either right click or pressing F5?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pywin32, win32com

[image: refresh]

I made a program (with C++) using `FindFirstChangeNotification()`, but this function does not have a way to detect the "refresh" action.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to trigger a refresh or are you pending on a refresh notification?  My understanding is that when a *widget* needs to be refreshed, Windows sends a notification to the widget or to the parent window.

Comment: `Refresh` is just an application convention.  It's just a design guide for a menu item.  What ID it sends and how each application responds to the menu command message is application specific.  There is no WinAPI component (message, function etc) that does a _"Refresh"_

Comment: `FindFirstChangeNotification()` only handles filesystem changes (files created/deleted/renamed, etc).  The screenshot provided is of the popup menu shown when right-clicking on the user's desktop. That is not going to "refresh" any filesystem items at all, only the ListView UI that the desktop uses to display its items. To detect that "refresh", you would have to hook the ListView itself to intercept window messages from the popup menu.

Comment: Ok, let me be clear, yes I am pending on a refresh notification. I am watching the changes on one folder with FindFirstChangeNotification(), but in addition I want if the user click on "refresh" in the folder, could catch this action.

Comment: What's the use case for this? The system isn't going to notify you of this because nobody thought that it would be useful to do so.

Comment: The use case is, when the user "refresh" the folder, the program catch this action and then send a notification to server and sync the files in the folder, like onedrive when you click-right on "refresh"

Comment: But OneDrive controls the `IShellFolder`, you don't.

Comment: The standard Refresh menu item will just call the current shell view Refresh method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellview-refresh. In standard shell views, it will just re-enumerate the view items. In file system shell views, it will just query the list of files and folders. Not sure why you want to hook to that. You could also hook shell notifications using SHChangeNotifyRegister https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotifyregister, closer to the shell changes than to file system changes.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's not recommended to break down Windows Shell. @Simon Mourier 's solution is absolutely more reasonable.